# DIV keeps on increasing it's height when adding DIV's . How to prevent this?

Tags: html, css

Trying to figure out how to not increase the height of class="sec1" div when adding more  100 inside the class="sec1_1". I don't wont to use pixels for height, want to keep %. I want to have an effect when adding 100 only for the scroll to expand. So the proportions between "sec1", "sec2", "sec3" to stay the same. To keep class="containerWithScroll" height=100% and the child div as well height=100%. Or using pixels for class="containerWithScroll" for the height is the only possible option?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">


<style>

.main_container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: red;
}

.sec1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  flex: 1;
}

.sec2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  position:relative;


}

.sec3 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  flex: 1;
}



.sec1_2 {
  width: 100%;
  /* height: 150px; */
}

</style>

</head>
<body>



  <div class="main_container">
    <div class="sec1" style="background-color: green;">
      <div class="sec1_2" style="background-color: yellow;">

        <div style="background:blue;display:flex;flex-direction:column;position:relative;width:100%;height:100%">



       
          <div style="background: blue;flex: 0 1 auto">      
            <div style="display:flex;flex-direction:column;height:100%;width:100%">
                 <h1>header</h1>
            </div>
         </div>

         <div style="background:lightblue;flex: 1 1 auto">   
          <div class="containerWithScroll" style="background: green;display:flex;flex-direction: column;height:100%">
            <div style="overflow-y:scroll;overflow-x: hidden;height:100%;width:100%">
              <div>100</div>
              <div>100</div>
              <div>100</div>
              <div>100</div>
              <div>100</div>
              <div>100</div>
              <div>100</div>
              <div>100</div>
              <div>100</div>
              <div>100</div>
              <div>100</div>
              <div>100</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          </div>
          
       
       </div>
       


      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="sec2" style="background-color: blue;">
      <div>2</div>
    </div>

    <div class="sec3" style="background-color: orange;">
      <div>3</div>
    </div>
  </div>

 

</body>
</html>
```